# Friendlier alternative to 'dogpile'

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

In a programming context, I want to use the term 'dogpile' like 'Let's all dogpile on this latest change, document what bugs exists and fix them'. ie. A group effort of everyone focusing on one particular thing.

The problem is - 'dogpile' has unfriendly connotations - it's often synonymous with bullying.

Is there an alternative word that doesn't have the bullying connotation?

Comment: I always thought that *dogpile* **was** the friendlier alternative to something now unprintable.

Comment: what’s wrong with “focus”?

Comment: "work together"

Comment: Or *gang up* on the problem. I thought dog pile was the polite term for canine excrement. Yeah! Let's all do that!

Comment: @Elliot Oh god. I hadn't even thought of that.

Comment: Ignoring scatological associations, the first entry in Urban Dictionary is unusually good: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dogpile and it shows that "dogpile" was not a good word to describe what you want.

Comment: *Spike* seems the current jargon, but is even more violent (referring to a spike as a brief increase in something, rather than a place you put something that's done).

Comment: @Greybeard unofficial slang dictionaries aside, dogpile probably have same origin as the dogfight (a medieval armed tournament skirmish mode of everyone vs. everyone). Dogpile is what you do in dogfight to overcome a significantly superior opponent. Today it's called swarm tactic.

Answer (score 1):

*If you want a verb:*

Let's all **jump** on this latest change, document what bugs exist, and fix them.

[**Jump on**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/jump+on):

2. To start something early or ahead of others, in order to gain an advantage.
   *If we want to beat the competition, we should really jump on this project now.*

*If you want a noun:*

**Jump-something**, e.g. jump list, jump issue, jump topic, jump task

You wouldn't be the first to use "jump" in a creative way.  For example, Windows has a [jump list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist?view=winrt-22621), which it defines as:

> A jump list is a system-provided menu that appears when the user right-clicks a program in the taskbar or on the Start menu.

This usage is not exactly the same as what you want -- it's things to jump *to*, whereas you want things to jump *on*.  But you get to provide the context to your colleagues in your other communications.

Alternatively you could use your word, *focus*: **focus list**, focus item[s], etc., or the already established **hot list**, hot topics, etc.

> [**hot**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hot): 6a: of intense and immediate interest

Comment: I'm looking for a noun. Basically something to name a slack channel. 'issue-jump-on' doesn't really work. Maybe 'issue-trampoline'.

Comment: @dwjohnston You're not looking for a noun in your question. In "let's all dogpile", *dogpile* is a verb.

Answer (score 0):

Collaborate (or collab, for short): It sounds more professional than other words or phrases.
From Oxford Languages, online:
collaborate - work jointly on an activity, especially to produce or create something.

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition for your suggestion to show how it fits the question.